# Interacting with Input and Output port of Pi

Tags: python, gpio

This are my python code for the interaction of GPIO of Pi

```
def gpio_control_on():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)

    # Delay only once when transitioning to ON state for GPIO 16 and GPIO 18
    if not GPIO.input(10):  # Check if GPIO 15 is LOW (was OFF)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 18 to HIGH
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 19 to HIGH
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Delay
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 18 to LOW
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 19 to LOW

    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control_off():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)

    # Delay only once when transitioning to OFF state for GPIO 16 and GPIO 18
    if GPIO.input(10):  # Check if GPIO 112 is HIGH (was ON)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 18 to HIGH
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 19 to HIGH
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Delay
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 18 to LOW
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 19 to LOW

    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

    pin5_value = GPIO.input(5)

    if pin5_value == GPIO.HIGH:
        gpio_control_on()
    else:
        gpio_control_off()

    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

From the above code, the pin of output will be high when there is no input given and vice versa. Why does the gpio of the board doesn't follow the condition that are written in the code? Based on the code above, when input is given at the input port, one of the output port is low. When I try using this code in the board, the code did not execute the following condition. why?

Have corrected the code above but still the GPIO don't give any response to the python code

```
import OPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def gpio_control_on():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)

    # Delay only once when transitioning to ON state for GPIO 16 and GPIO 18
    if not GPIO.input(24):  # Check if GPIO 8 is LOW (was OFF)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 12 to HIGH
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 16 to HIGH
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Delay
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 12 to LOW
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 16 to LOW

    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control_off():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)

    # Delay only once when transitioning to OFF state for GPIO 16 and GPIO 18
    if GPIO.input(24):  # Check if GPIO 8 is HIGH (was ON)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 12 to HIGH
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set GPIO 16 to HIGH
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Delay
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 12 to LOW
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)  # Set GPIO 16 to LOW

    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

    pin24_value = GPIO.input(24)

    if pin24_value == GPIO.HIGH:
        gpio_control_on()
    else:
        gpio_control_off()

    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.cleanup()

# Call the gpio_control function
gpio_control()
```

is there any hardware issue that I should consider?

Comment: A single GPIO pin is either input or output.  You can't use one pin in both directions, as you are attempting with pin 10.

Comment: @TimRoberts, it’s not true. How bidi pins are configured? That’s how I2C bus, for example, works. So, the question is if the pin can and is configured as a such and is the PCB level of hardware designed for that?

Comment: That misses the point.  At any point in time, a GPIO pin is either input or output.  To change direction, the pin has to be reconfigured.  That's not being done here.  Even with I2C, the side in control has to tri-state the pin in order to turn it around.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I already found out the possible cause of the not readable python code on the hardware. the config file of the hardware that have been built before is missing. am trying to configure the hardware again